# Animal Ontology

Tags: rdf, ontology, owl

I am looking for ontology like an animal ontology where I can get the hierarchy, e.g.

```
Bird
==>Duck
======>Mallard_Duck
```

I have seen this one, http://www.bbc.co.uk/ontologies/wildlife/2010-11-04.shtml, but so far I'm not successful in getting the hierarchy through sparql, is it possible to do it with it??

If not, does someone know an animal ontology thats displays the hierarchy??

Comment: How is this related to programming? This seems off topic.

Comment: I need it to perform query expansion

Comment: Question is related to programming (semantic web) and should be re-open. Quick answer: Hierarchies can be represented using RDFS (http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-schema/), you can assert that `Mallard_Duck rdfs:SubClassOf Duck` and that `Duck SubClassOf Bird`.

Comment: @user1774937 The BBC employs content type negotiation on their website, so you can take the URL that you have, http://www.bbc.co.uk/ontologies/wildlife/2010-11-04.shtml, and replace `.shtml` with `.rdf` and get the ontology from http://www.bbc.co.uk/ontologies/wildlife/2010-11-04.rdf.  From there, you can run SPARQL queries against it, load it in Protégé, etc.  Using the `pellet` commandline tools, you can view the hierarchy, too. E.g. http://pastebin.com/argdV4N9.

Comment: @loopasam This might be a bit too broad for a good StackOverflow question (and it might be better on answers.semanticweb.com), but since it does seem relatively answerable, I've cast a reopen vote.

Comment: You can search for here http://lov.okfn.org/dataset/lov/.